# Uso de "embarcar" como "situarse algo fuera del alcance"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, españa

Recuerdo cuando era pequeño, hace muchos años, que hubo una época en la que nos dio por jugar al béisbol en unos jardines universitarios poco frecuentados por aquel entonces, por lo que no molestábamos (mucho). Cada vez que alguien le atinaba a la pelota demasiado fuerte y la enviaba a algún tejado de algún edificio cercano, decíamos

> ¡Hala, ya has embarcado la pelota!

Para mí, el uso de *embarcar* con el significado de "colocar algo en un lugar inalcanzable" era (y sigue siendo) de lo más normal. Sin embargo, luego aprendí que dicho significado ni siquiera lo contempla la RAE. Por tanto, debe de ser un modismo muy localizado en la zona de Cádiz (España) y alrededores. El habla de esta zona está muy influenciada por el mar y los marineros, por lo que no es raro encontrar términos prestados por dicho oficio. A fin de cuentas, cuando un marinero se embarca y zarpa, queda fuera del alcance de los que se quedan en tierra.

La pregunta es ¿se entiende esta expresión en otras partes fuera de la zona del estrecho y alrededores? Con el auge de Internet, términos que en principio sólo pertenecen a una zona se pueden expandir más rápidamente. En caso negativo, ¿qué otros términos con el mismo significado figurado se usan en otras partes del mundo para la misma situación?

Comment: Si puede ser de alguna ayuda, en Italia tenemos la misma expresión, "_hai imbarcato il pallone_!", por lo menos en Roma.

Comment: @moonwave99 ¡interesante! Me gusta mucho el italiano, lo hablo un poco de hecho, pero no sabía que se usara esa misma expresión.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe un artículo al respeto en el blog http://unaracnidounacamiseta.com/2014/09/05/cuando-alcanzas-la-pelota-dices/

Aunque en Cataluña usaba *colar*: *¡Se ha colado!*

> - Embarcar (Ourense, A Coruña, Sevilla, Cádiz, Almería).
> - Botar la pelota (Barranquilla, en Colombia).
> - Encalar (Huesca y Castellón).
> - Encolar (Palencia, al menos en el pueblo de Almostel).
> - Enmarcar (Pontevedra).
> - Encanar (Murcia).
> - Encallar (en catalán).
> - Colgar (Barcelona).
> - Empeñar (Málaga).
> - Colar (Euskadi, Cáceres, Madrid).
> - Encajar (León).
> - Volar la bola (Ciudad de México).

Comment: No me suena _encallar_ en catalán. _Colarse_, sí.

Comment: En Zaragoza también decíamos *colgar*.

Comment: @fedorqui encal(l)ar sí que está documentado en valenciano. Desconozco si en otras variedades de catalán, pero no me extrañaría que fuésemos los barceloneses la excepción (no sé si lo eres).

Comment: @guillem el [dcvb](http://dcvb.iecat.net/) menciona _encalar_ sin especificar la región, así que debe ser de sobra conocido (menos para mí :'(, que soy de pueblo). Eso sí, _encallar_ aparece, pero proviniendo del castellano y con distinto significado (vagamente parecido, en cuanto a dejar de funcionar algo)

Comment: En Almería decimos embarcado también. Pero así es la pronunciación correcta: La bola sambarcao.

Answer (score 1):

En mi opinión, sí, se expande a otras regiones de España. Yo, por ejemplo, soy de la zona de Galicia y hemos utilizado innumerables veces (tanto mis amigos como yo) la frase "has embarcado la pelota".

Diría que es una expresión muy usada en todo el país pero habría que ver si en el resto de provincias es algo común o se considera una "falta", tal y como lo considera la RAE.